# Transpose and Paste VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Currently from my sheet2, I wanted to copy the column C36-N36. However, each of these cells has one formula that is generated from the numbers within sheet2, i.e. C36 = A1+A2/2 something like this. Therefore, simply copy & paste code cannot work well when I transfer to sheet 1, as the specific link of each cell will be gone, and barely the values were left.

Therefore, when I try to copy and paste C36-N36 to sheet 1's L3-L14, I used the above codes. I do not simply want to copy and paste the final numbers, since the codes allow the numbers can be change simultaneously. For example, if C36's number changed in sheet 2, sheet1's L3 will change accordingly by the system too.

HOWEVER, the current issue is that it cannot be transposed, as C26-N26 is in a row, while L3-L14 is in a column. Does anyone know where to add the transpose code to my current codes?

```
Sub CopyPaste1sttry()

Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet

Set wsSource = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set wsTarget = Worksheets("Sheet1")

wsSource.Range("C36:N36").Copy


wsTarget.Range("L3:L14").Activate
wsTarget.Paste Link:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using this site to have existing working code reviewed and maybe improved. For questions like your one, where you ask how to do a specific thing or how to fix an issue then please use the sister site [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

That being said, you could achieve the desired result with a loop. For example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet: Set wsSource = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet: Set wsTarget = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rngSource As Range: Set rngSource = wsSource.Range("C36:N36")
    Dim rngTarget As Range: Set rngTarget = wsTarget.Range("L3:L14")
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Long: i = 1
    
    For Each cell In rngTarget
        cell.Formula = "=" & rngSource.Cells(1, i).Address(External:=True)
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Please note that hardcoding the range addresses and sheet names in VBA is a bad idea if you need to change things in the future but also for maintainability. Consider creating 2 named ranges (via Excel/Formulas/Name Manager) and referring to those instead so that in case sheet names are changed or ranges position/size is changed then the code does not fail or even worse produce the wrong results.

For example, I would create the 2 named ranges:
[image]

[image]

and then use something like an auxiliary function:

```
Private Sub LinkRanges(ByVal sourceName As String _
                     , ByVal targetName As String)
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngTarget As Range
    '
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngSource = ThisWorkbook.Names(sourceName).RefersToRange
    Set rngTarget = ThisWorkbook.Names(targetName).RefersToRange
    On Error GoTo 0
    '
    If rngSource Is Nothing Or rngTarget Is Nothing Then
        Err.Raise 5, , "Missing required ranges"
    ElseIf rngSource.Areas.Count > 1 Or rngTarget.Areas.Count > 1 Then
        Err.Raise 5, , "Multi-area ranges not allowed"
    ElseIf rngSource.Rows.Count > 1 And rngSource.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        Err.Raise 5, , "Source is a matrix. Expected row or column"
    ElseIf rngTarget.Rows.Count > 1 And rngTarget.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        Err.Raise 5, , "Target is a matrix. Expected row or column"
    ElseIf rngSource.Count <> rngTarget.Count Then
        Err.Raise 5, , "Source and Target have different number of cells"
    End If
    '
    Dim arrFormulas() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    '
    ReDim arrFormulas(1 To rngSource.Count)
    i = 1
    For Each cell In rngSource
        arrFormulas(i) = "=" & cell.Address(External:=True)
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
    i = 1
    For Each cell In rngTarget
        cell.Formula = arrFormulas(i)
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
End Sub
```

that can be called like this:

```
Sub Test()
    On Error Resume Next
    LinkRanges "rngSource", "rngTarget"
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Err.Clear
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    '
    'Do whatever else
    '
    '
End Sub
```

This way you prevent any future errors and you are also able to re-use the `LinkRanges` method to link a column to a row not just row to a column.

Comment: Please refrain from answering off-topic questions. There are plenty of valid questions that could use your expertise instead.

Comment: @Mast Will do from now on. Thanks!